# How can I meantioning a user in a slack slash command?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

In the documentation, they say that the new way to mention a user is **<@userID>**, however when I do that the slack doesn't convert that string into the user mentioning.

Do I need to change something in the slack configuration?

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. There should be no need to change any configuration. Please post the relevant part of your code so people can help solve your issue better. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code. that would be helpful in this case.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, but I found the problem. In the block that I wanted to mention a user, the block type was plain_text instead of mrkdwn. Now it is working properly.